# Off-site Computational Science community promotion ads

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, site-promotion

Hi Computational Science!

I'm currently updating [a meta.physics.se post that encourages members to support other scientific SE sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites). Several of those sites are in Area 51 and get an automatic advert like this one:

[Computational Science http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/28815.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/28815.png)

The other beta sites, on the other hand, tend to already be forming some sort of graphic identity and already have adverts that can be used to promote those betas on other SE sites. For example, take a look at the ones for [Astronomy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/off-site-astronomy-community-promotion-ads), [Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/ideas-for-off-site-space-exploration-community-promotion-ads), or [Robotics](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/help-promote-robotics-with-community-promotion-ads-2014).

Those adverts are particularly useful for promoting a beta site through the Community Promotion Ads on launched sites. Those are adverts which are shown on the right sidebar and which are proposed and voted on by the community of each site in a dedicated meta question (like, for example [this one from Physics.se](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/community-promotion-ads-2014).)

So, what am I proposing? **It would be cool if you guys can come up with advert ideas that can be used to promote Computational Science.SE in other related SE sites.** This community knows the strengths and selling points of the site best, so give it a go!

Adverts in the Community Promotion 'range' need to follow some fairly strict guidelines, because they are automatically processed by the SE engine (i.e. they're taken straight from the corresponding meta question by an automated process). To inform your design process, I include a copy of those guidelines below.

**For clarity, I am not asking for adverts to show within Computational Science, but for adverts to promote it in other site. Beta sites do not have their own community promotion ads.**

---

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
>   show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
>   question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
>   provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
>   shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to
>   visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following
>   things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your
>   community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote
>   information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's
>   interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to
>   join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other
>   things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads
>   every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served
>   their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This
>   helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject
>   matter of the community, but to the current status of the community.
>   We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an
>   ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very
>   valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good
>   idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the
>   process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale
>   after a year of exposure.
>
> #### How does it work?
>
> The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following
>   rules, or they will be ignored.
>
> 1. All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
>    ```
>    [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
>
>       [1]: http://image-url
>       [2]: http://clickthrough-url
>    ```
>
>    Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
> 2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the
>      functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the
>      answer form with the above required form.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

Answer (score -1):

Now that Computational Science is no longer in Beta, I recommend that we do the same thing as what they have on the Physics Meta. We still have **nine** proposals in [Science on Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=hot). This is a way to give back to the younger science communities, now that Computational Science achieved success in graduating (with some help from ads like the one on Physics Meta that OP told us about here).